# Não consigo validar atributos de classe @Embeddable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

Estou com problema de validação na classe Endereço que está `@Embeddable` ao tentar fazer um `POST`.

Quando eu coloco por `null` no campo `nome` que é da `Pessoa` por exemplo, eu consigo capturar a mensagem de customizada até aqui ok! Mas quando eu coloco `null` em qualquer atributo da classe `Endereco` que está `@Embeddable` eu não consigo validar e mostrar mensagem customizada.

Segue o erro:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-04-15T01:34:19.071+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support. (ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)\n\t... 111 more\n",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/pessoas"
}
```

Segue um exemplo do meu JSON, e as classes `Pessoa` e `Endereco`:

```
{
    "nome": "Dayson Rodrigues Mota",
    "ativo": true,
    "endereco": {
        "logradouro": null,
        "numero": 90,
        "complemento": "324",
        "bairro": "Testeeee",
        "cep": "234",
        "cidade": "234",
        "estado": "ld"
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.algamoney.model;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa" )
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10,max = 60)
    private String nome;
    @NotNull
    private boolean ativo;
    
    @Embedded
    private Endereco endereco;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (ativo ? 1231 : 1237);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pessoa other = (Pessoa) obj;
        if (ativo != other.ativo)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.algamoney.model;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Embeddable
public class Endereco {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 60)
    private String logradouro;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    private String numero;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    private String complemento;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String bairro;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 9)
    private String cep;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String cidade;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    private String estado;

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para considerar validação de classes internas, você deve utilizar a anotação `@Valid` da JSR-303, conforme descrito [nessa sessão da documentação](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e991)

Dessa forma, sua declaração da classe `Endereco` ficaria desta forma:

```
@Valid
@Embedded
private Endereco endereco;
```

Um exemplo dessa utilização também encontra-se [nessa sessão da documentação](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e2808).

Comment: Show de Bola deu certo! Agora só uma duvida, no caso da mensagem para o usuário, ele aparece assim quando coloco null; 
**"msgUsuario": "endereco.cep precisa ter entre 4 e 9 caractéres."** 
No caso como faço para pegar só o campo dentro da Classe Endereco?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, poderia elaborar um pouco mais?

Comment: De qualquer forma, @daysonrodrigues não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta :)

Comment: Eu coloquei dentro do Classe Endereco um @Size(min 9,max=10) no atributo CEP, mas quando eu coloco um tamanho menor conforme informado, mostra-se uma mensagem customizada que eu criei através de um arquivo, mas a mensagem informada é **endereco.cep precisa ter entre 4 e 9 caractéres.** como faço para mostrar só o atributo CEP? 

No meu arquivo que criei Validation.properties coloquei a mensagem assim: avax.validation.constraints.Size.message={0} precisa ter entre {min} e {max} caract\u00e9res.

Answer (score -1):

Dayson para customizar o nome do atributo você pode utilizar o arquivo "messages.properties" para atribuir uma descrição mais clara para o usuário. Por exemplo: endereco.cep=CEP

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).